# Open HTML page with Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I want to show the page that loads my latest [google reviews](https://www.thepcwow.com/ajax/gur.html) with Magnific PopUp...

the reference is as follows:

`<a class="lstrev btn btn-3d btn-xs btn-tertiary mb-2" href="ajax/gur">`

Code to action:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){$(".lstrev").magnificPopup({type:"ajax",mainClass:"mfp-fade",alignTop:"true",overflowY:"scroll",callbacks:{ajax:{closeBtnInside:"true",dataType:"html",cursor:"mfp-ajax-cur",tError:'<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.'}}})});
</script>
```

My Problem is that I only got a bar at the top of the page as you can see 
[here](https://www.thepcwow.com/test.html), Click the button "Top Rated IT Solutions" at the very top in the right side of the page (not available from mobile devices, table and computers only)